# Error while running Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium

While running the Selenium WebDriver code, I get the following error message.

> Microsoft Windows Malicious Software Removal Tool - ... wants to restore your Chrome settings to their original defaults

This is the code I am using.

```
 package snaptrude;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;   
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

    public class MyProject {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // declaration and instantiation of objects/variables

            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\Kunal\\Desktop\\Selenium\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

            String baseUrl = "http://demo.guru99.com/test/newtours/";
            String expectedTitle = "Welcome: Mercury Tours";
            String actualTitle = "";

            // launch Fire fox and direct it to the Base URL
            driver.get(baseUrl);

            // get the actual value of the title
            actualTitle = driver.getTitle();

            /*
             * compare the actual title of the page with the expected one and print
             * the result as "Passed" or "Failed"
             */
            if (actualTitle.contentEquals(expectedTitle)){
                System.out.println("Test Passed!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Test Failed");
            }

            //close Fire fox
            driver.close();

        }
    }
```

Comment: It looks like a problem with Chrome, not Selenium. Have you tried resetting the defaults and rerunning?

Comment: Yup, I have already done that

Comment: Try updating your ChromeDriver version?

Comment: It's the latest version

Comment: @Kunal Update the question with the error stack trace.